# AS3: ByteArray sound data loop smoothing issue

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays

I've made a SoundEnvelope class to keep a split attack/sustain sample pair. The class also preprocesses the sustain loop to crossfade with the last chosen amount of stereo samples of the attack chunk, and the 30 ms MP3 encoder offset gets trimmed for proper playback.

Both trimming and looping are imperative for my project.

Now, the attack builds up fine, smoothly goes into the sustain loop, but the loop seems to be skipping some data at the end, and it seems to be dominantly related to the crossfading effect, it's probably a timing issue but I just can't seem to find the problem.

For those who aren't familiar with dynamically processed sounds, here's the [function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29), I'm using a loop with an if-else fork to decide if the chunk goes in the attack or the sustain variable of my SoundEnvelope instance.

**[ UPDATE ]**

**`@A Shelly:`** A sound envelope in a professional synthesizer consists of an attack-decay-sustain-release sequence. In my case, the attack and decay are the same portion, and the release is just fading out the volume of the sustain, which needs to loop back into itself smoothly.

Let's say, we have a raw trumpet sample that goes like *tfweeeewweeeewweeeewweeeep*, and my extract consists of `_a` = *[tfweeeew]* and `_s` = *[weeeewweeeewwe]* portions. Now, this could be any sample, and I'm using a uniform 0.5 sec attack and 1.0 sec sustain loop here. So, to make it sound continuous, I need to fade out the end of the loop, since it doesn't match its own beginning, and fade in the attack portion's end part at the same time, which would make the sample tiling seamless. Of course, this would produce a slight breathiness in the sample's endpoint, but it's still better than having it pop while looping like *...deewdeewdeewdeewdeew...*

**[ CODE ]**

Here's the looping function, I really hope someone can help me, thanks in advance:

```
public function fadeLoop(fadeStereoSamples:uint):void {

    var volume:Number;
    var helper:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var fade:Number;

    // moves the pointer to the overlapping part's beginning of sustain and attack ByteArrays
    // _a and _s are the two chunk arrays in the SoundEnvelope object
    _a.position = _a.length - fadeStereoSamples * 8;
    _s.position = _s.length - fadeStereoSamples * 8;

    // crossfade through input amount of sample-pairs
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < fadeStereoSamples; i++) {

        fade = i / fadeStereoSamples;

        // fadestep left
        helper.writeFloat(_a.readFloat() * fade + _s.readFloat() * (1 - fade));
        // fadestep right
        helper.writeFloat(_a.readFloat() * fade + _s.readFloat() * (1 - fade));

    }

    _s.position = _s.length - fadeStereoSamples * 8;

    for (i = 0; i < fadeStereoSamples; i++) {

        helper.position = 0;

        _s.writeFloat(helper.readFloat());
        _s.writeFloat(helper.readFloat());

    }

    _a.position = 0;
    _s.position = 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a better description of the glitch?   Perhaps doing a test where you use 2 distinctive sounds for _a and _s (a high vs low frequency sinewave?) would let you see the problem in a plot of the output.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I had to ditch this approach due to my deadline. I will most likely come back to it out of personal interest at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: isn't the fact that `fade` never equals 1 the origin of your problem? You may probably write `fade = i / (fadeStereoSamples - 1)`.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It actually decides only the volume between the two mixed waveforms.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to fade out _a and fade in _s?  It looks like you are doing the opposite - _a gets louder toward the end.

Also, why are you starting at the end of _s, instead of the beginning?  Shouldn't you mix the end of _a with the beginning of _s?

And I'm not sure why you describe that section as looping.  There should be only one transition per attack, right?   If you call that multiple times, _s will get quieter and quieter since you are overwriting it.

Comment: I wrote an example to explain why I fade it the way I do. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I've never used ActionScript, but I have written a MIDI synth, so I understand what you are trying to solve.  I'm confused by the very last part of your code, where you write the crossfaded segment back into the tail of _s.  Will _s get reloaded from source before you call this function again? If not, it seems like you will progressively mix in more and more _a, changing it from a linear fade to an exponential one.

Comment: Or is this called only once as preprocessing ?  In which case, I would look at your audio API calls, since this looks reasonable.